# How to add stacklabels for stacked bar chart where data is loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, html, highcharts

How to add stacklabels for stacked bar chart where data is loaded dynamically.For example, On click of a button every new 5 data will be displayed in the chart , in such a case the stacklabels dont display , what to do?

Comment: can you post a working example showing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For the click function of your button you can add new series like this and `redraw` the chart:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].addSeries({ name: 'Test', data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] });
Highcharts.charts[0].redraw();
```

And for stacklabels to show, just add this to your `yAxis`:

```
stackLabels: {
    enabled: true
}
```

Here's an example with working `stacklabels` and dynamically loaded data on click of a button : http://jsfiddle.net/qhv8dfa0/1/

Comment: @StephenMuecke your reason is much more accurate, but not the first one. Better now?

Comment: @Opal Someone has already asked for clarification. The question is so general that I must give a tutorial. And actually it does provide an answer.